# Salvage code from files in .cache > JetBrains folder

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, autosave

I reinstalled Ubuntu and seem to have lost python code that I had written in PyCharm.
After a lengthy search, I have found a ".cache" folder (on a portable SSD, in .Trash-1000 with a JetBrains subfolder contained inside it).

Is there a way I can salvage some of the code from these files?
How should I go about it?

I've included a picture that shows which folders and files are present.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If anything it should be in `LocalHistory`. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/local-history.html . Not going to advise on how to actually extract anything from there. Check the IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) sources for some ideas I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move this folder to $HOME/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1